# Extract first element from multi dimensional array from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame consists of `reviews` column which is a `multi dimensional array`, I would like to extract first element as shown below,

Suppose `df['Reviews']` consists of following `rows`

[image: Reviews Data]

I want the output in a separate column as shown below,

[image: Output]

Please find sample data 3 values for the column below:

df['Reviews'] =
[['Just like home', 'A Warm Welcome to Wintry Amsterdam'], ['01/03/2018', '01/01/2018']]
[['Great food and staff', 'just perfect'], ['01/06/2018', '01/04/2018']]
[['Satisfaction', 'Delicious old school restaurant'], ['01/04/2018', '01/04/2018']]

Please help

Comment: Add your code where you're making the `df`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need first lists use indexing by `str[0]`:

```
import ast

df['Reviews'] = df['Reviews'].apply(ast.literal_eval).str[0]
```

If need join lists by `,` to strings add [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
import ast

df['Reviews'] = df['Reviews'].apply(ast.literal_eval).str[0].str.join(',')
```

Comment: It only extracts '[' as a value in the new column. I've shared sample 3 rows from the data set so that you can replicate the issue. Thanks

Comment: @RohanWaje - Can you test now?

Comment: It worked on the sample which I've shared but when I applied on entire data it threw "ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x0000015D77551E48>" error. Any suggestions?

Comment: @RohanWaje - It means there are some data problem.

Comment: @RohanWaje - sometimes help `import yaml` and `df['Reviews'] = df['Reviews'].apply(yaml.load).str[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in the following for your dataframe access as per your need.
This will create a new column named **output** with the appropriate requirement

**Apply Function**

```
df['output'] = df.Reviews.apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

**Map Function**

```
df.loc[:, 'output'] = df.Reviews.map(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: Following error is received for both the suggested code:
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should help. This worked for me.

```
df['Reviews']=df['Reviews'].apply(lambda c: str(c[0]).strip('[]'))
```

This works fine if run once.If run again on same code, it ll further divide the text.So i suggest comment it out after using it.
Or make a new column.

P.S: You should include the code instead of screenshots so that it can be tested first.

**EDIT**
[image]
Looks fine to me.try once again and remember if you run it twice (incase not making separate column), it ll return none

Comment: It doesn't return anything in the new column. I've attached sample 3 rows from data set to replicate it. This is my first post to stack, I'll note your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: I ll take the screenshot of my output.Have a look at this

Comment: It works on sample data, but when applied to entire data I get this error "ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x0000015D16D73A48>". Unable to find the data issue if any.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive error, you probably have some empty data in Reviews. You can drop them, if such data is useless for you:
`df.dropna(subset='Reviews', inplace=True)`

or add checking type of data:

```
a = [[['Just like home', 'A Warm Welcome to Wintry Amsterdam'], ['01/03/2018', '01/01/2018']], [['Great food and staff', 'just perfect'], ['01/06/2018', '01/04/2018']], [['Satisfaction', 'Delicious old school restaurant'], ['01/04/2018', '01/04/2018']]]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Reviews', 'Review'])
df['Reviews'] = a
df
```

```
executed in 18ms, finished 07:39:04 2020-06-05
Reviews Review
0   [[Just like home, A Warm Welcome to Wintry Ams...   NaN
1   [[Great food and staff, just perfect], [01/06/...   NaN
2   [[Satisfaction, Delicious old school restauran...   NaN
```

```
def get_review(reviews):
    if type(reviews) == list:
        return reviews[0]
    else:
        return None

df['Review'] = df['Reviews'].apply(get_review)
df
```

```
    Reviews Review
0   [[Just like home, A Warm Welcome to Wintry Ams...   [Just like home, A Warm Welcome to Wintry Amst...
1   [[Great food and staff, just perfect], [01/06/...   [Great food and staff, just perfect]
2   [[Satisfaction, Delicious old school restauran...   [Satisfaction, Delicious old school restaurant]
```

If you don't want column `Review` to be a list, simply covert it to string with some divider:

```
def get_review(reviews):
    if type(reviews) == list:
        return ', '.join(reviews[0])
    else:
        return ''

df['Review'] = df['Reviews'].apply(get_review)
df
```

```
    Reviews Review
0   [[Just like home, A Warm Welcome to Wintry Ams...   Just like home, A Warm Welcome to Wintry Amste...
1   [[Great food and staff, just perfect], [01/06/...   Great food and staff, just perfect
2   [[Satisfaction, Delicious old school restauran...   Satisfaction, Delicious old school restaurant
```

I your input data is not of type list (i.e. you reading it from CSV), you need to convert it to list first:

```
import ast

def get_review(reviews):
    if pd.notna(reviews) and reviews != '': 
        r_list = ast.literal_eval(reviews)[0]
        if len(r_list) > 0:
            return ', '.join(r_list)
        else:
            return ''
    else:
        return ''

df2['Review'] = df2['Reviews'].apply(get_review)
df2
```

```
Reviews Review
Reviews Review
0   [['Just like home', 'A Warm Welcome to Wintry ...   Just like home, A Warm Welcome to Wintry Amste...
1   [['Great food and staff', 'just perfect'], ['0...   Great food and staff, just perfect
2   [['Satisfaction', 'Delicious old school restau...   Satisfaction, Delicious old school restaurant
```

Comment: It only creates a column with values "None". I've shared sample 3 rows from the data set to replicate it. Thanks

Comment: @RohanWaje, I've used sample data, and it works for me on Python 3.6 and pandas 1.0.3 .